# Disable text selection UITextView

Tags: iphone

I want to disable text selection on a UITextView. Until now what i've 
already done is:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {   
  [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;   
  if (action == @selector(paste:))   
    return NO;   
  if (action == @selector(select:))   
    return NO;   
  if (action == @selector(selectAll:))   
    return NO;   
  return NO;   
}
```

In this away I set UIMenuController to hidden and i put a stop to text copy but the text selection is still visible.

Google results (also StackOverflow) take me to no solution. Has someone already faced the 
same problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent the text selection but keep links interactions, add the following textview delegate methods

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)];
}
```

Comment: This will crash the application if theres any attempt to backspace.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable cut/copy/paste on **all** `UITextView` of your application you can use a *category* with :

```
@implementation UITextView (DisableCopyPaste)

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

It saves a subclassing... :-)

Otherwise, just subclass `UITextView`and put :

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: The question is about disabling text selection on a `UITextView` and this is what this piece of code does...

Comment: This will also disable text input though surely? Yeah, just tested. This disables any text input to the text field.

Answer (score -1):

```
textView.editable = NO;
```

or

```
[textView setEnabled:NO];
```

im not sure what u meant