# iPhone UITextView Highlighting On Tap Hold

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

How do i remove this?

I have removed the paste/copy menu... using:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender    
{    

            return NO;


}
```

but i need the uitextviews text to be non selectable and only able to be typed into.

Comment: the uitextviews text. (sorry my mistake)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896340/disable-text-selection-uitextview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639485/uitextview-disabling-text-selection, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397857/how-to-disable-select-functionality-in-uitextview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193032/uitextview-how-to-disable-highlighting Sorry to say none of those questions seems to have got a strait and easy to implement answer.